# Jenkins sending emails for manual builds

Tags: email, jenkins

Does anyone know of a Jenkins plugin or script that would send out emails when someone does a manual build?  We currently have a scheduled daily build for our dev env, but once in a while we need to do a manual build and I would like Jenkins to send an email out when this happens to warn our team that a build is in progress.  But I don't want Jenkins to send out emails for the daily build because I think we all can agree that we get too many system emails.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [extended email plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin) to send an email at the start of a build.

Obviously this means you will have to have separate manual and daily build jobs, but it's the best solution I've been able to come up with so far. If you use downstream job chains, you can still chain the same jobs to the manual and scheduled build so that the workflow remains the same and you don't need duplicates of all jobs in the chain.